# Php how get meta tags name from url page

Tags: php, meta-tags

i try to get name from meta tags.

I get meta tags like this :

```
$test = get_meta_tags('http://viedemerde.fr');
```

then :

```
echo $test['description'];
...
```

I have the description, but without :

```
meta name="description
```

How can i get this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get_meta_tags Does fetch only meta data without additional html tags or info

Here is a code that fetches all meta and information about any webpage use the way you want for your code:

You should get your meta @`$test["metaTags"]["description"]["html"];`

in fallowing code or you can use it the way you would want to

```
function getUrlData($url) {
$result = false;

$contents = getUrlContents($url);

if (isset($contents) && is_string($contents)) {
    $title = null;
    $metaTags = null;

    preg_match('/<title>([^>]*)<\/title>/si', $contents, $match);

    if (isset($match) && is_array($match) && count($match) > 0) {
        $title = strip_tags($match[1]);
    }

    preg_match_all('/<[\s]*meta[\s]*name="?' . '([^>"]*)"?[\s]*' . 'content="?([^>"]*)"?[\s]*[\/]?[\s]*>/si', $contents, $match);

    if (isset($match) && is_array($match) && count($match) == 3) {
        $originals = $match[0];
        $names = $match[1];
        $values = $match[2];

        if (count($originals) == count($names) && count($names) == count($values)) {
            $metaTags = array();

            for ($i = 0, $limiti = count($names); $i < $limiti; $i++) {
                $metaTags[$names[$i]] = array(
                    'html' => htmlentities($originals[$i]),
                    'value' => $values[$i]
                );
            }
        }
    }

    $result = array(
        'title' => $title,
        'metaTags' => $metaTags
    );
}
return $result;}


function getUrlContents($url, $maximumRedirections = null, $currentRedirection = 0) {
$result = false;

$contents = @file_get_contents($url);

// Check if we need to go somewhere else

if (isset($contents) && is_string($contents)) {
    preg_match_all('/<[\s]*meta[\s]*http-equiv="?REFRESH"?' . '[\s]*content="?[0-9]*;[\s]*URL[\s]*=[\s]*([^>"]*)"?' . '[\s]*[\/]?[\s]*>/si', $contents, $match);

    if (isset($match) && is_array($match) && count($match) == 2 && count($match[1]) == 1) {
        if (!isset($maximumRedirections) || $currentRedirection < $maximumRedirections) {
            return getUrlContents($match[1][0], $maximumRedirections, ++$currentRedirection);
        }

        $result = false;
    } else {
        $result = $contents;
    }
}

return $contents;}

$test = getUrlData('http://ocsidtechnologies.com');  //Replace  with your URL here
echo '<pre>';print_r($test);
```

Comment: @ ShaH : How can i get my all META Tags like category wise, is possible?

Comment: @Rathinam I think the above code is answering the same code please copy the code in local system and browse the file to check or just paste the code in phpfiddle and run to see category wise meta tags like author,description,keywords etc

Comment: Yes, i saw the details, may i know how can i get my all categories meta tags... like bulk exports using anything..?

Comment: @Rathinam Can you explain the quition properly or open a new thread if this is not related